# Autoloader filter duplicates

Tags: azure, pyspark, spark-streaming, azure-databricks, databricks-autoloader

Im heaving streaming dataframe and wonder how can I eliminate duplicataes plus select only latest `modifiedon` row.

For example.

| id | modifiedon |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/08/2023 |
| 1 | 03/08/2023 |
| 2 | 02/08/2023 |
| 2 | 03/08/2023 |

Desired df

| id | modifiedon |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/08/2023 |
| 2 | 03/08/2023 |

**So, if there is the idential (100%) identical rows, like id 1, it needs to drop all and keep only 1 row per ID. and also, if the same ID is represented multiple times (updated multiple times) I need to pick based on the maximum modifiedon column.**

```
df = (
    spark.readStream
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("quote", '"')
    .option("mode", "permissive")
    .option("lineSep", "\r\n")
    .option("multiLine", "true")
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", source_format)
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_directory)
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("escape", '"')
    .schema(schema)
    .load(data_source)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow below approach.

Below is the data I used.

[image]

```
df = df.dropDuplicates().withColumn("modifiedon",to_timestamp("modifiedon","dd/MM/yyyy"))
df = df.withWatermark("modifiedon", "1 day")
df = df.groupBy("id").agg(max("modifiedon").alias("modifiedon"))
display(df)
```

Here, over period of 1 day on streaming data apply aggregation and do max on the column `modifiedon`.

Output:

[image]

Comment: I think I need to import max function and then it worked. Only thing is that I cant display the `df` to see if this really works

Comment: You can use `display` function or write to console.

Comment: well, I know about `display(df)` but it does not work. also, my real df contains alot more columns but it only has `id` and `modifiedon` columns

Comment: ok then try to write the file as csv and check it or get the count `df.count()`.